# Which of these heatsink technology would be better?

Tags: cooling, heatsink

as per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/create-a-stack-exchange-site-for-pc-hardware) I think I should direct this question to this site.

Having been a computer enthusiast for a while I have yet to build my own computer, but I'm at it now for this Christmas period and I find myself overwhelmed with the quantity of different pieces and materials available in the market; in a few years hardware technology has advanced quite a lot.

I'm considering two heat sinks, the [Hyper 412S](http://www.coolermaster.com/product.php?product_id=6748) and the [Hyper 612S](http://www.coolermaster.com/product.php?product_id=6727) both from Cooler Master. They're kind of similar but the technology used seems to be different.

The 412S has 4 direct contact heat pipes, which judging from the screenshots in their website seem to be made of aluminum. The 612S has 6 copper made joint together in a copper base.

I always thought aluminum alloys to conduct better than copper, but the pipes in the 412S are not joint in a base but *attached* to the heat sink itself.

Does anyone know about these technologies/materials? I'd appreciate any experience with any of those techs too, it doesn't have to be the same models or anything.

Comment: `I always thought aluminum alloys to conduct better than copper`. No. Copper conducts heat better. Aluminum is better at dissipating it.

Comment: Oh, I see... so when dissipating heat aluminum would be better than copper; thank you for the info.

Comment: Aye. Hence many designs with copper plates to conduct the heat away from the base (and optionally heat pipes to do the same) and aluminum cooling fins.